# Java Encryption and C# Decryption Issue

Tags: c#, java, encryption-symmetric

I have a DLL in C# that encrypts and decrypts string texts (something basic), but now I need to implement the same encryption method in Java, so that some applications can encrypt data and send it to the library.

I can't modify the C# code, because it's already in production, but the Java don't, so please, any suggestion must be done at the Java side.

Basically I'm trying to implement the same C# encryption method in Java. Here are my C# codes:

**NOTE**: the passphrase, salt, etc. values obviously are just referential.

```
    const string PassPhrase = "IhDyHz6bgQyS0Ff1/1s="; 
    const string SaltValue = "0A0Qvv09OXd3GsYHVrA=";   
    const string HashAlgorithm = "SHA1";                
    const int PasswordIterations = 3;                 
    const string InitVector = "GjrlRZ6INgNckBqv";      
    const int KeySize = 256;


public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {

        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitVector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltValue);


        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);


        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(
                                                        PassPhrase,
                                                        saltValueBytes,
                                                        HashAlgorithm,
                                                        PasswordIterations);


        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);


        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();


        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;


        ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(
                                                         keyBytes,
                                                         initVectorBytes);


        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();


        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
                                                     encryptor,
                                                     CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);


        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();


        byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();


        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();


        string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);


        return cipherText;
    }


public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {

        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitVector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltValue);


        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(
                                                        PassPhrase,
                                                        saltValueBytes,
                                                        HashAlgorithm,
                                                        PasswordIterations);


        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);


        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();


        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;


        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(
                                                         keyBytes,
                                                         initVectorBytes);


        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);


        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
                                                      decryptor,
                                                      CryptoStreamMode.Read);


        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];


        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes,
                                                   0,
                                                   plainTextBytes.Length);


        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();


        string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes,
                                                   0,
                                                   decryptedByteCount);


        return plainText;
    }
```

Here is my java code, it encrypts the data, but not at the same way as the C# encryption code, so when I try to decrypt it using the C# library it throws the exception: "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid"

```
    static final String PassPhrase = "IhDyHz6bgQyS0Ff1/1s=";   
    static final String SaltValue = "0A0Qvv09OXd3GsYHVrA=";    
    static final String HashAlgorithm = "SHA1";               
    static final int PasswordIterations = 3;                   
    static final String InitVector = "GjrlRZ6INgNckBqv";       
    static final int KeySize = 256;

public static String encrypt(String plainText)
{
    char[] password = PassPhrase.toCharArray();
    byte[] salt = SaltValue.getBytes();
    byte[] iv = InitVector.getBytes();
    byte[] ciphertext = new byte[0];

    SecretKeyFactory factory;
    try {
        factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, PasswordIterations, 256);
        SecretKey tmp;

        tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);

        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        //iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    //catch (InvalidParameterSpecException e) {
    //  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //  e.printStackTrace();
    //} 
    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Base64.encode(new String(ciphertext));
}
```

**EDIT 1**: I fixed the final byte array conversion to String in the Java code, as Jon Skeet suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what's wrong, in the Java code:

```
return Base64.encode(ciphertext.toString());
```

You're calling `toString()` on the byte array, which will *always* give a string such as `[B@3e25a5`.

EDIT: Ooh, just noticed that you *can* change the Java side. Hooray.

Basically, you need to use a Base64 API which allows:

```
return Base64.encode(ciphertext);
```

I'm always disappointed in Base64 APIs which *allow* you to "encode" a string, to be honest... base64 fundamentally encodes binary data to text, and decodes text data to binary. Oh well...

Anyway, use [this API](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) (the `encodeBytes` method) if you need one which allows you to pass in a byte array.

I haven't checked over the actual encryption part in detail, but the C# code at least *looks* like it's doing the right thing in terms of encodings. It could do with `using` statements though :)

Comment: Thank you, you were right, there was an error in that part of the Java code, I fixed it and now I get the right encoded text, but still it cannot be decrypted using the C# code (same exception), for example I encrypt: Hello World with the posted C# method and get ["fawkThB32M8FsbOxn05KEw=="] and in Java it's much longer ["bigIxbgKxaHDizUuP8OlR1bCsMOnw78="] why could this be happening? Am I missing the Initial Vector somewhere it should be?

Comment: Things to try: #1 check if the used base64 variants follow the same rules wrt adding newlines, etc. #2 check if the encoded text can be decoded by java.

Comment: I checked the decoding results and they match on both sides, I'm pretty sure the problem is that the keys are not matching because of this: "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1", .Net use PBKDF1 by default. I've been searching the web and found out that Bouncycastle can handle this by creating a key with PBKDF1 using this method somehow: PKCS5S1ParametersGenerator but sadly the post doesn't elaborate anymore on the solution to this. Any clues here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# example, you need the IterationCount and PaddingMode.None

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = "";
    string password = "";
    string salt = "";
    string iv = "";


    byte[] vectorBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Server.UrlDecode(iv)); 
    byte[] cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(Server.UrlDecode(value));

    Rfc2898DeriveBytes key1 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, StringToByteArray(salt)); //same as PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
    key1.IterationCount = 32;
    byte[] keyBytes = key1.GetBytes(16);

    string Answer = DecryptDataAES(cipherText, keyBytes, vectorBytes); //vectorBytes is good

    //litAnswer.Text = Answer;
}

public static string DecryptDataAES(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    string plaintext = null;

    using (Rijndael rijndael = Rijndael.Create())
    {
        rijndael.Key = key;
        rijndael.IV = iv;
        rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(rijndael.Key, rijndael.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption. 
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return plaintext;
}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length / 2;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars];
    using (var sr = new StringReader(hex))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i++)
            bytes[i] =
              Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() }), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: This example helped me out.  Not sure why, but for my situation, I didn't need to set the Padding.  Otherwise this worked as needed.  Thx.